# Functional analysis on manifolds

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, soft-question

The basic object of functional analysis is the topological vector space, so vector spaces with some topology, we can add additional structure by introducing metrics etc, but the underlying object is a linear space anyway.

I was wondering if there's any field of math that still studies functionals, but defined on manifolds instead of vector spaces.

Comment: I think a functional is usually understood to be linear, i.e. to respect the linear structure. So what is meant by "functional" if the underlying structure is not linear?

Comment: the user, can you define some sort of linear manifolds?

Comment: @PeterMelech I don't think the linearity is implied, since we have tools from calculus of variations or other theorems in general that allow to study non linear functional, but to my knowledge they're still defined on some sort of topological vector space.

Comment: @SujitBhattacharyya Planes, Banach spaces, Hilbert spaces, I assume all of these are "linear manifold". But of course what I'm asking is related to "non linear manifolds".

Comment: @user8469759 I didn't know about non-linear functionals. Would be curious to see an example and a justification to still call it a functional.

Comment: @PeterMelech Anything really that given a function returns a scalar value. Norms are an example. Pick $f \in \mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{\Omega})$ the squared norm of $f$, i.e. $$ \lVert f \rVert_2^2 = \int_{\Omega} |f(x)|^2 dx $$ is a functional, because given an element of that vector space returns a scalar value. As you know norms aren't linear, but sublinear.

Comment: @user8469759 OK, didn't know about this usage of the term functional. In the wikipedia article  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_(mathematics)) it is said, that functionals are scalar mappings "for the purpose of establishing a calculus-like structure", this is of course at the heart of the idea of a manifold.

Comment: What was your definition instead? Usually in functional analysis they specify the linearity of a functional (like explicitly).

Comment: Yes, I looked it up right know, You are right, as opposed to the usual definition in linear algebra, in functional analysis one usually talks about linear functionals, if they are supposed to be linear. I somehow mixed this up.

Comment: I honestly don't remember a formal definition of "functional" in linear algebra, what I do remember is the definition of dual space, which is the sets of all linear maps that map vectors to scalar values. Just looked up on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_form, I would assume a distinction would be necessary though.

Answer (score 1):

I know, I am late to the game, but what you are really looking for are [Banach manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_manifold).

These are geometric spaces that are *locally* modelled on Banach spaces much like smooth manifolds are modelled on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and hence are a non-linear version of Banach spaces. If the linear Banach space model is non-separable, such infinite-dimensional manifolds are even more interesting.

Furthermore, you can model infinite-dimensional non-linear spaces on all kinds of infinite-dimensional linear spaces, e.g. [Frechet manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_manifold).

Comment: I think what I'm also looking for is some $L^p(X)$ space where X is not necessarily an infinite dimensional manifold.

Comment: Why do you think so? $L^p$-spaces are supposed to be linear spaces, regardless of $X$. Also, no idea if there exists such a thing as $L^p$-space on an infinite-dimensional manifold $X$, but probably it does. An infinite-dimensional manifold that locally looks like $L^p(X)$ sounds pretty interesting thing to consider.

Comment: I probably don't explain myself well. But yes I'm looking to construct linear spaces, of functions, whose domains is some measure space on a finite dimensional manifold. I struggle to find references but I know these formulations are used somewhere.

Comment: @user8469759: Ah, I see. That makes a lot of sense. On manifolds, you are interested not just in integration, but also in the smooth structure, so this is usually done in the context of Sobolev spaces. For example, see the book Hebey - Sobolev Spaces on Manifolds. The purpose of these is usually the analysis of geometric PDEs, i.e. PDEs on manifolds arising from some geometric problem. There are also $L^p$-spaces of differential forms since this is one natural setting of integration on manifolds. I think you should also probably have a look at Federer's seminal book "Geometric Measure Theory".

Comment: @user8469759: Forgot to mention, since you were talking concretely about *functionals*, the smooth manifold analog of this is called currents: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_(mathematics) (should be also in Federer's book)